# Cannot get closure syntax to work in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, swift4, completionhandler

I've tried every syntax variation that I can, but the *completion handler* always activates before the end of the animation. I think I'm supposed to replace `Bool` with something else?

```
UIView.transition(with: swipeForPicturesIndicator,
                              duration: 1,
                              options: .curveEaseIn,
                              animations: {
                                self.swipeForPicturesIndicator.alpha = 0
            },
                              completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                self.swipeForPicturesIndicator.isHidden = true
                self.swipeForPicturesIndicator.alpha = 0.8
            })
```

Comment: Is the completion closure being called immediately?

Comment: Are you running any other animations? The `Bool` will tell you whether the animation was cancelled or did not finish (`false`), or if it finished successfully (`true`). See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686922/what-exactly-does-bool-parameter-do-in-animatewithdurationanimationscompletion?rq=1

Comment: What do you actually see on the screen and what do you expect?

Comment: Based on the description, I suspect the goal is for the indicator to gradually fade out (alpha to 0) and after 1 second, the indicator is legit hidden.  And the claim here is that the indicator is just immediately getting hidden (i.e. no fade).

Comment: That said, I think you might actually want to use the animate method rather than the transition method.

Answer (score 1):

The `Bool` value indicates wether the animation was finished when the completion block was called. If that value is `false` it means your animation was interrupted.

You should use probably `animate` instead of `transition`

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
                   delay: 0,
                   options: .curveEaseIn,
                   animations: {
      self.swipeForPicturesIndicator.alpha = 0
    }) { (completed) in

      /* Optionally check if animation finished */

      self.swipeForPicturesIndicator.isHidden = true
      self.swipeForPicturesIndicator.alpha = 0.8
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.swipeForPicturesIndicator.alpha = 0
UIView.transition(with: swipeForPicturesIndicator,
                              duration: 1,
                              options: .curveEaseIn,
                              animations: {

                self.swipeForPicturesIndicator.alpha = 0.8

            },
                              completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use animate instead of transition:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: { 
        self.swipeForPicturesIndicator.alpha = 0
    }) { (success) in
        self.swipeForPicturesIndicator.isHidden = true
        self.swipeForPicturesIndicator.alpha = 0.8
    }
```